# How to make notepad++ NOT to replace spaces for TAB?

Tags: tabs, notepad++

How to make notepad++ NOT to replace spaces for TAB?

Simultaneously, I wish it use TAB if I press TAB.

Comment: Settings > Preferences... > Tab Settings

Comment: And what then? A don't want to turn on "Replace by space".

Comment: If the "Replace by space" flag is turned off, then Notepad++ should not replace Tabs with Spaces. In my Notepad++ v6.7.7 it works like a charm.

Comment: The problem is reverse: it replaces spaces with tabs. For example, if you press space 4 times, it will replace this 4 spaces with 1 tab. I want to turn of this functionality.

Comment: I've never seen such functionality in Notepad++. You may try to reinstall the editor. But I think that it may be some another software which works in background and causes such behavior. Something like puntoswitcher or autohotkey... Or, maybe, you've installed some plugins.

Answer (score 5):

In the Menu: Settings > Preferences > Tab Settings

set "Replace by space" to OFF **for the currently used language**.

According to your comment i understand you say "Replace by space" is OFF already. But maybe not for the currently used language.

E.g. if you have opened a python file (or selected "python" as language), and
 "Replace by space" is OFF for the "[Default]", but ON for python, it still would replace Tabs by spaces.

Comment: The settings dialog for it can be misleading too.  Tab Settings is now a frame on the right side of the Language section in preferences. Don't select a language in the 'Language Menu' center pane like I did and then look to see if 'Replace by space' is checked. Instead, scroll down the list of languages in the Tab Settings pane to the one you care about, select it, and change it as needed (also, setting the default the way you want it might be a good idea).